# how to find vmware/vsphere templates with java api

Tags: java, virtual-machine, vmware, vsphere

In vsphere java SDK there is Browser sample class that shows how to list virtual machines

```
ManagedObjectReference containerView =
vimPort.createContainerView(viewManager, folder,
Arrays.asList("VirtualMachine"), true);
```

How can I check if such virtual machine is template ?
Or better how to query about template virtual machines, so as to get only templates in soap response ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check a VM is template or not. You can check for `vm_obj.config.template` .

The `VirtualMachine` manged object has the property `config` which is of type `VirtualMachineConfigInfo` . And in the `VirtualMachineConfigInfo` you can find the boolean `template` property.

Comment: do I have to fetch all virtual machines from vcenter and than in java check config.template, or it is possible to filter them and fetch only managed object references with config.template = true ?

Comment: You have to iterate through all the VMs and have to check the template property. So for each vminfo `VirtualMachineConfigInfo vminfo = vm.getConfig();` Check `vminfo.isTemplate()`